# SQL combine two tables into rows in one table

Tags: sql, join, union, druid

Looking to combine two tables into one, as separate rows, so that I can then run GROUP BY, COUNT and general aggregations over them. They both have the same column names and types.

I'm looking for the simplest way to do this, rather than the most efficient - i.e without using UNION (which isn't available), and although JOINs are fine if it could be done without that would be better, as the system I'm using has pretty basic sql functionality.

For example:

Table 1:

```
Name        Age
A           20
B           32
C           45
```

Table 2:

```
Name        Age
B           54
E           38
```

Combined:

```
Name        Age
A           20
B           32
C           45
B           54
E           38
```

Edit:
I’m using Druid Sql - although UNION ALL is available the result cannot be used as a sub query (due to how translation works), and so cannot run GROUP BY or aggregate functions on the combined table, which is really what I’m looking for. Is there a way to do this combine without using union?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using and explain why "Union isn't available".

Comment: I’m using Druid Sql - although UNION ALL is available the result cannot be used as a sub query, and so I cannot run GROUP BY or aggregate functions on the combined table, which is really what I’m looking for.

Comment: KIndly edit the relevant tags and information into your Question, instead of putting it in a comment.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, first time poster! Have updated the question

Comment: You can achieve what you want by using FULL JOIN, but I think full join is not available in Druid. If it is, let me know

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing is `union all`:

```
select name, age
from table1
union all
select name, age
from table2;
```

`UNION ALL` is standard SQL and is available in all databases that I'm familiar with.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I’m using Druid Sql - although UNION ALL is available the result cannot be used as a sub query, and so I cannot run GROUP BY or aggregate functions on the combined table, which is really what I’m looking for.